# How to ignore ruff errors in jupyter notebook in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ruff

I am using ruff to lint and format my Python code in Visual Studio Code. I also work often with jupyter notebooks inside VSCode. When I do that I get some ruff linting errors that don't really make sense in a notebook such as `Module level import not at top of cell`:

[image]

In a Python file, this warning certainly makes sense, but not really in a notebook. I couldn't find how I could silence these warnings for notebooks specifically. There are no ruff settings related to notebooks and I couldn't find how to apply settings specifically to jupyter notebooks. Does somebody know how to silence these warnings inside a notebook in VSCode?

Comment: "There are no ruff settings related to notebook". That statement seems to differ from what the FAQ says, see ['Does Ruff support Jupyter Notebooks'](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/faq/#does-ruff-support-jupyter-notebooks) and [this issue tracking list entitled 'Complete Jupyter notebook integration'](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/5188). Particularly relevant to the rest of you question, you may want to see [this now closed issue](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-vscode/issues/256) that was part of that list that had said in July 'No, Jupyter Notebook in VSCode isn't supported yet'.

Comment: <continued> In particular regards to the title of your post there is [this discussion entitled 'module level E402 inside notebook cells'](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-vscode/issues/340). If you follow somethings you'll end up [here](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/8669#issuecomment-1830252676) where it says, "For notebooks, we'd check the rule for each cell so "Module level import not at top of cell".  Does any of that point you to how to better deal with this? I suspect ...

Comment: <continued>  [that](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-vscode/issues/340#issuecomment-1807601362) could be adapted to what you want?